# recognizer Queue from Voce library is not giving intended ouput during launch

Tags: java, eclipse, speech-recognition

I am using Voce library to make speech recognition program in Java and my code is not going in the loop even after following through sample code from Voce site.

```
    //INITIALIZING INTRO
    AudioInputStream intro = null;  

    //INTERFACE BETWEEN USER AND MONA IS INITIALIZED
    MaryInterface marytts = null;

    try {
        String s = null;

        //INTERFACE IS CREATED
        marytts = new LocalMaryInterface();
        //THE FIRST TIME MONA IS INVOKED
        intro = marytts.generateAudio("HELLO.MY NAME IS MONA.HOW CAN I HELP YOU?");
        MaryAudioUtils.writeWavFile(MaryAudioUtils.getSamplesAsDoubleArray(intro), "mona.wav", intro.getFormat());

        voce.SpeechInterface.init("C:/Users/X/Documents/LunaWorkspace/Galvin/lib", false, true, 
                "file:/C:/Users/X/Documents/LunaWorkspace/Galvin/lib/gram", "actions");

        System.out.println("Before while");
        //The value for getRecognizerQueueSize turns out to be 0
        while(voce.SpeechInterface.getRecognizerQueueSize() > 0)
        {
             s = voce.SpeechInterface.popRecognizedString();

        }

        System.out.println("Did you say"+voce.SpeechInterface.getRecognizerQueueSize()+"?");

        System.out.println("After while");

        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start wmplayer.exe");


    } catch (Exception e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        System.out.println("end");
```

Comment: You can use sphinx4 directly I presume

Comment: Have you looked at the value returned by voce.SpeechInterface.getRecognizerQueueSize() ?

Comment: @azurefrog I don't where my code is going wrong.If the method is returning 0 that means that voice is not being recorded.I don't know why?

Comment: @relational_programmer You might want to [edit] your question text and title to make that focus more clear.  Currently your question sounds like you're asking about while-loops, rather than why the recognizer queue is empty.